# How do I fit a UISearchBar in a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, uisearchcontroller

I'm using a UISearchController in iOS 8 and when I make its UISearchBar my table's header view everything is fine. However now I need it in my UINavigationBar's left bar button (can't be the title view because of the vertical centering when I enlarge the nav bar). When I wrap the UISearchBar in a UIBarButtonItem it is larger than the width of the screen.

[image: off screen search bar]

I think it is related to my view controller initialized from a storyboard with size classes enabled which means my frames are not set till `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. However I had the same issue with my segmented control in a toolbar and I just called `sizeToFit` on the toolbar in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and that fixed the toolbar. When I do the same for the search bar it still draws partly off screen. Apple does this in some of their iPad apps but how?

Note: I can hack it to get it all on screen but I have to wrap it in another view but then the color is off and it just seems wrong and I think the animation is off.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a UIBarButtonItem with UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace with -10 width which will remove 10 px padding.

```
UIBarButtonItem *Spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[Spacer setWidth:-10];
UISearchBar *searchBar= [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-10, 39)];
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Spacer,searchBarItem,nil];
```